# python/gtk application produces different results CLI vs Launcher

Tags: python, linux, gtk, environment-variables, aptitude

I have a python application which is basically a front end for aptitude. The strange thing is the program produces different results depending on whether it is launched from the GUI (via the .py, a desktop launcher or a sym link) or whether it is called on the cli.

Below is the code and screenshot

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import gtk
import pygtk
import os
import sys
import re
import getpass

get_username = getpass.getuser()
class createUI:
####################   
    def on_column_clicked(self, col1, col2, col3, col4 ):
            #This function allows the columns to be resorted upon click

            if sort_order == gtk.SORT_ASCENDING:
               sort_order = gtk.SORT_DESCENDING
            else:
               sort_order = gtk.SORT_ASCENDING
####################               
    def install_selected(self, option):
            #This function determines which field has been selected
            #Then it picks the package name from the second column 
            self.selection = treeview.get_selection()
            self.selection.set_mode(gtk.SELECTION_SINGLE)
            #We only want the user to be able to select one file
            tree_model, tree_iter = self.selection.get_selected()
            #The line below is the line which determines which column is passed to the installer
            self.selected_program = tree_model.get_value(tree_iter, 1)    
            print self.selected_program
            os.system("gksudo 'aptitude install %s -y'" % self.selected_program)
##################
    def search_packages(self, clicked):
        #this is the function which searches for the packages and stores the list in a file
        #for easier manipulation. It starts by trying to remove any temp files in case there was not a clean shutdown
        #previously
        try:
            os.system('rm -rf /home/%s/.tux_search/somefile' % get_username)
        except:
            pass
        search = self.search_package.get_text()
        os.system("aptitude search %s > /home/%s/.tux_search/somefile" % (search,get_username) )
        if search != "":
            #Call the results        
            self.createTable()
            #destroy the search window
            self.window.destroy()
        else:
            pass    
#############
    def kill_program(self, click):
        #attempt to clean up before quitting
        os.system('rm -rf /home/%s/.tux_search/somefile' % get_username)
        gtk.main_quit()
#####################    
    def uninstall_program(self, click):
        #this section functions in the same way as the install package except it purges files instead of installs them
        self.selection = treeview.get_selection()
        self.selection.set_mode(gtk.SELECTION_SINGLE)
        tree_model, tree_iter = self.selection.get_selected()
        self.selected_program = tree_model.get_value(tree_iter, 1)    
        os.system("gksudo 'aptitude --purge remove %s -y'" % self.selected_program)
####################            
    def __init__(self):
        self.create_search(None)
##################        
    def create_search(self, dummy):
        try:
            self.aptitude_results.destroy()
        except:
            pass
        #create the initial search window
        self.window = gtk.Window()
        #centre the window
        self.window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        #We set the default because otherwise the dialogue box looks disproportionate
        self.window.set_default_size(300,150)
        self.window.set_title("Search for a Package")

        #Deal with the search label. It goes inside of an Hbox for horizontal positioning
        self.vbox = gtk.VBox(spacing=10)
        self.search_label_hbox_1 = gtk.HBox(spacing=10)
        self.label = gtk.Label("Please enter a program to search for :")
        self.search_label_hbox_1.pack_start(self.label)

        #Add the entry box for user input, again in an Hbox
        self.search_entry_hbox_2 = gtk.HBox(spacing=10)
        self.search_package = gtk.Entry()
        self.search_entry_hbox_2.pack_start(self.search_package)

        #add the buttons
        self.buttons_hbox_3 = gtk.HBox(spacing=10)
        self.button_ok = gtk.Button("Get Results!")
        #the results button calls the 'search_packages' function
        self.button_ok.connect("clicked", self.search_packages)

        self.buttons_hbox_3.pack_start(self.button_ok)
        self.button_exit = gtk.Button("Get me Outta Here!")
        self.buttons_hbox_3.pack_start(self.button_exit)
        self.button_exit.connect("clicked", gtk.main_quit)

        #here we put the hboxes inside of the vbox (verticle box)
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.search_label_hbox_1)
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.search_entry_hbox_2)
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.buttons_hbox_3)

        #add everything to the main window and display it       
        self.window.add(self.vbox)
        self.window.show_all()
        gtk.main()
#####################3        
    def createTable(self):
        global treeview
        builder = gtk.Builder()
        builder.add_from_file('/home/%s/.tux_search/aptitude_frontend.glade' % get_username)
        builder.connect_signals(self)
        self.aptitude_results = builder.get_object('window')
        treeview = builder.get_object('treeview')
        table_vbox = builder.get_object('vbox')

        treestore = builder.get_object('liststore1')

        cols = ["Installed?", "Package Name", "Description"]
        treeview.cell = [None] * len(cols)
        treeview_column = [None] * len(cols)

        for column_number, col in enumerate(cols):
            treeview.cell[column_number] = gtk.CellRendererText()
            treeview_column[column_number] = gtk.TreeViewColumn(col, treeview.cell[column_number])
            treeview_column[column_number].add_attribute(treeview.cell[column_number], 'text', column_number)
            treeview_column[column_number].set_resizable(True)
            treeview_column[column_number].set_reorderable(True)
            treeview_column[column_number].set_sort_indicator(True)
            treeview_column[column_number].set_sort_column_id(column_number)
            treeview.append_column(treeview_column[column_number])

        #read the output from aptitude
        fetch_results = open("/home/%s/.tux_search/somefile" % get_username).readlines()
        #A results list is required to get rid of all the wierd spaces that aptitude produces for terminal output
        results_list = []


        for single_result in fetch_results:
            #turn the results into a tuple by splitting at the spaces
            #this allows us to get rid of the spaces
            single_result = single_result.split(" ")
            counter = 0
            place_holder = []
            while counter < len(single_result):
                #here we are checking to see if a line starts with a space/tab/new line and has nothing else
                if re.match(r'^\s*$', single_result[counter]):
                    #we dont want to append these so instead we will just pass over them
                    pass
                else:
                    place_holder.append(single_result[counter])                    
                counter +=1
            #the place holder is required so that we can turn each tuple back into a string so that it can be appended to the actual results list
            place_holder = " ".join(place_holder)
            #get rid of the new line characters if they exist
            place_holder = place_holder.rstrip()
            results_list.append(place_holder)

        for column_contents in results_list:
            column_contents = column_contents.split(" ")
            #since the information was entered into the list in the following way "i eog - <package_description>"
            #we want to put all the descriptive words into a single element so they can be placed into
            #a column. We can also tell that the descriptions start at the 4th element
            element = 3
            package_description = []
            while element < len(column_contents):
                package_description.append(column_contents[element])
                element +=1
            package_description = " ".join(package_description)

            #This section translates the 
            if column_contents[0] == "i":
                column_contents[0] = "y"
                treestore.append(
                    [ column_contents[0], column_contents[1], package_description ]
                    )

            elif column_contents[0] == "v":
                #skip the meta package information
                pass
            elif column_contents[0] == "p":
                column_contents[0] = "n"    
                treestore.append(
                    [ column_contents[0], column_contents[1], package_description ]
                    )

        #add the tool bar for 'nice' buttons
        toolbar = builder.get_object('toolbar')

        #quit button
        quit_icon = gtk.Image()
        quit_icon.set_from_file("/home/%s/.tux_search/icons/quit.png" % get_username)
        quit_button = gtk.ToolButton(label="Quit!", icon_widget=quit_icon)
        toolbar.insert(quit_button, 0)
        quit_button.connect("clicked", self.kill_program)

        #uninstall button
        uninstall_icon = gtk.Image()
        uninstall_icon.set_from_file("/home/%s/.tux_search/icons/uninstall.png" % get_username)
        uninstall_button = gtk.ToolButton(label="Uninstall!", icon_widget=uninstall_icon)
        toolbar.insert(uninstall_button, 0)
        uninstall_button.connect("clicked", self.uninstall_program)

        #install button
        install_icon = gtk.Image()
        install_icon.set_from_file("/home/%s/.tux_search/icons/working_tux.png" % get_username)
        install_button = gtk.ToolButton(label="Install", icon_widget=install_icon)
        toolbar.insert(install_button, 1)
        install_button.connect("clicked", self.install_selected)    
        toolbar.show()

        #search button
        search_icon = gtk.Image()
        search_icon.set_from_file("/home/%s/.tux_search/icons/tux_search.png" % get_username)
        search_button = gtk.ToolButton(label="Search Again", icon_widget=search_icon)
        toolbar.insert(search_button, 2)
        search_button.connect("clicked", self.create_search)

        table_vbox.show()
        self.aptitude_results.connect("destroy", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
        self.aptitude_results.set_default_size(600, 800)
        self.aptitude_results.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        self.aptitude_results.show_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    createUI()
```

and the glade file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="2.24"/>
  <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment1">
    <property name="upper">100</property>
    <property name="step_increment">1</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkListStore" id="liststore1">
    <columns>
      <!-- column-name Installed? -->
      <column type="gchararray"/>
      <!-- column-name Package Name -->
      <column type="gchararray"/>
      <!-- column-name Description -->
      <column type="gchararray"/>
    </columns>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkVBox" id="vbox">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkToolbar" id="toolbar">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="toolbar_style">both</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">False</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scrolledwindow">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="vadjustment">adjustment1</property>
            <property name="hscrollbar_policy">automatic</property>
            <property name="vscrollbar_policy">automatic</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkTreeView" id="treeview">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="model">liststore1</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

since I can't post screen shots my photobucket screen shots can be found
http://i57.photobucket.com/albums/g239/Stratus_ss/cli.png

http://i57.photobucket.com/albums/g239/Stratus_ss/gui.png

Comment: Found my mistake, my fetch line was fetching the wrong file

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I'm glad you solved your problem yourself! But let me point out that you're likely to get a quick response if you post a small code sample that isolates your problem, instead of a giant code dump. People don't read giant code dumps. Also, more often than not, when I'm preparing a small code sample, I am able to find the problem myself like you were. Good luck!